Not able to access User Assigned Identity from the container in Azure App Service
I have a web app in Azure which runs a Windows container with a python server. I need to access keyvault from the application, therefore I assigned user identity to it and gave it access to read secrets from keyvault. When the application is trying to access secrets I see the following log:
non-io error occurred which will not be retried

Caused by:
    0: failed to get bearer token
    1: Multiple errors were encountered while attempting to authenticate:
       error getting environment credential
       error getting managed identity credential
       error getting token credential from Azure CLI
error getting managed identity credential


this seems to me that the identity was not accessible to the app.

If I use system identity instead it just works.
There are some options that I tried already that didn't help:

Setting keyVaultReferenceIdentity in webapp properties to the user identity
Restarting the app.
SSHing into the container and querying identity with az login --identity - got this exception:

MSI: Failed to retrieve a token from 'http://100.64.100.2:41401/msi/token//?resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&api-version=2017-09-01' with an error of '{"statusCode":400,"message":"Unable to load the proper Managed Identity."


Please provide more details about the issue.

Hi, could you please indicate what details are needed? I can fetch anything from the app, please suggest which information would be valuable

How you are deploying your app?Also provide the code of keyvault configuration.

gave it access to read secrets from keyvault.  Have you given permission for your app in Access Policy` Image

Is your Keyvault based on RBAC or Vault access policy. Image

The Azure web app is unable to fetch Key Vault secrets using its assigned identity, and there are multiple causes of this problem.
1.Make sure to verify that the correct user-managed identity is assigned to the web app


Check the Key Vault configuration for the access policy. If it is set to use RBAC, change it to use Access Policies.


Then, navigate to the access policy section, create a new policy with the required permissions (GET and LIST), and select your user-assigned identity.

Ensure you check the network restrictions (firewall settings) on the key vault, as these may be blocking access from your web app.
Follow the  Use a managed identity to connect Key Vault to an Azure web app in .NET for more details.

@vopix,  I hope this helps to resolve your query.
